# Android Programming: ListView CheckBox gone visible

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, visible, invisible

I am creating a ListView with checkbox that is initially Visibility:Gone. I want to view all the checkboxes when I long press an Item but some of the items does not display a checkbox and it changes when I scroll. I want to make it the same way as a messagin app where I can delete multiple items by selecting multiple checkboxes.

```
lists[0].setLongClickable(true);
    lists[0].setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckBox selectAll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
            selectAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            int count = lists[0].getChildCount();
            int adapter = myAdapter[0].getCount();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Integer.toString(adapter), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter; i++) {
                View v = (View) lists[0].getItemAtPosition(i);
                CheckBox box = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSelect);
                box.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    myAdapter[0].notifyDataSetChanged();
    lists[0].setAdapter(myAdapter[0]);
```

[This is the output of my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4erA.png)

Comment: you need to maintain state of visible and invisible checkboxes..for that i think you need to created a model class..storing the value Visible or Gone..and based on that update checkbox in adapter..

Comment: I'm confused about your use of `Array`. Is `list` an array of lists and `myAdapter` an array of adapters? If so, why?

Comment: @NicolásCarrasco I made it an array so that I can modify it in inner classes.. I created a final Adapter array with a size 1 only..

Comment: @Meenal How do you do that, exactly?

Comment: @user3872163 it is unnecessary to turn those into arrays, you can manipulate the adapter from inside inner classes as well and the code would be cleaner to read. Having said that I don't really know why your code isn't working